# keil arm - how to share variable between bootloader and user app

Tags: arm, keil

Keil ARM uVision4, Processor LPC1768
Is is possible to share a variable at a defined location in memory for bootloader and user app to set/view this variable?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to setup your memory space correctly.

One solution is to setup a section of memory in your Scatter-loading Description file so that the memory will not be initialized by going between the boot and the application.  For example, you could setup a section called `NoInit` by setting aside a segment of memory -

```
RW_IRAM0 0x100000000 UNINIT 0x0000001F {
    *(NoInit)
}
```

Then in both your boot and application you could define a variable that resides in that space:

```
static unsigned long system_flags __attribute((section("NoInit"), zero_init));
```

Hope that helps to put you on the right track!

Comment: If you're doing such things, you may also want to protect this memory range to make sure, it is still valid after a soft reset. E.g. calculating a CRC over that block

Comment: Thanks, great help.  This application is using ethernet dhcp for connectivity.  DHCP runs in bootloader and again in user app.  Would it also be possible to use shared memory for passing ethernet connection structures between the bootloader and user application.  Other recommendations to allow running DHCP only once..?

Comment: @whitedog I imagine that you could make it work.  You would have to make sure your `NoInit` section was defined to be large enough in the Scatter-loading Description file and then use the same attribute as shown above when you define/initialize your structure.